# Java list files in a folder avoiding .DS_Store

Tags: java, macos, list

When I try to list files in a folder with this:

```
String file;
File folder = new File("/Users/francesco/Desktop/VIDEOS");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
BufferedReader br = null;
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++){
```

It reads also the .DS_Store file inside the folder, giving me a lot of errors. How can I avoid to read these .DS_Store files in Java?

Comment: Check whether the file is named `.DS_STORE`?

Comment: I was thinking about checking if the file start with "." but I can't figure out how to do it

Comment: Look at the functions in the `String` class.

Comment: You have to include a condition to check `if the file name contains the word  .DS_Store` then skip it`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass a `FileNameFilter` to `File.listFiles` to filter out the one you don't want.

```
    File[] files = folder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return !name.equals(".DS_Store");
        }
    });
```

EDIT:  Java 8 lambda version

```
    File[] files = folder.listFiles((dir, name) -> !name.equals(".DS_Store"));
```